# How i configure monit to start a process with a specific user?

Tags: linux, monitoring, unix, monit

Monit runs with root, but i don't want to start my processes as root.. like mysql, mongrel, apache..

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
 check process tomcat with pidfile /var/run/tomcat.pid
       start program = "/etc/init.d/tomcat start" 
             as uid nobody and gid nobody
       stop program  = "/etc/init.d/tomcat stop"
             # You can also use id numbers instead and write:
             as uid 99 and with gid 99
       if failed port 8080 then restart
```

[(source)](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html)

Answer (score 2):

i have found a answer.. i could do a: start_program = "su -c 'command here' USERiWANTtoUSE"..
:)

Comment: or can use a option 'as uid USERNAME and gid GROUPNAME'. For ex:
start_program = "command" as uid USER and gid GROUPNAME

Comment: it's better if you edit your answers with this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to run as another user a specific command

```
exec /bin/su - userName -c "/usr/bin/nginx start"
```

This will run that command `" "` as the user you defined

Answer (score -1):

What operating system / distro are you using? How did you install Monit? Most dsitros 'do the right thing' and make sure things don't start as root.

Comment: i'm using debian sarge.. i've installed with apt-get.. i don't think monit can be started as other user than root.. by the way it can?..
:)

Comment: monit can be run by any user with `monit -c .monitrc`