# Monit: How to check a program executed by a specific user?

Tags: monit, mmonit

I have been using [`monit`/`mmonit`](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor my system. One if its features is the `check program` syntax, which runs a program and validates its return value:

```
# Asserts that there are more than 40 users in the DEV DB.

check program more_than_40_users_in_dev_db 
    with path /home/ubuntu/servers-scripts/monitoring/more_than_40_users_in_dev_db.py
    with timeout 5 seconds
    every 2 cycles
    if status != 0 then alert
```

The problem is that the script should run as the user `ubuntu`, but monit runs it as `root`. I have tried the [`as uid ubuntu and gid ubuntu`](https://serverfault.com/questions/50628/how-i-configure-monit-to-start-a-process-with-a-determinated-user) syntax, but it does not seem to work for the `check program` directive.

Is there a way to run this script as a specific user?

Comment: Heh, I wanna know what's in: `/home/ubuntu/servers-scripts/monitoring/more_than_40_users_in_dev_db.py` :)

Comment: One of the most mundane scripts ever written by a human being.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably changed in the intervening few years, but you can now do this with the `as uid abc and as gid abc` syntax as long as monit is running as root (e.g. systemd service):

```
# You can also shorten to 'as gid user and uid user'; both formats work for me with v5.26.0
check program somescript with path /home/user/somescript.sh as gid user and as uid user
    if status != 0 then alert
```

Where somescript.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami > /home/user/whoami.out
```

Of course you can also use a different `gid` that user is part of (say `sharing`) and the resulting file will be created with ownership `user:sharing` and contain 'user'.